# Trying to reverse a string using c

Tags: c

Platform : C

Hi, 
   I am trying to reverse the string in the following format:

Input string: This is a cat

Output String: siht si a tac

The code which I have implemented is this:

```
int main()
{

    char str[100];
    char final[100];
    int len=0;
    int i=0;
    char temp[100];
    int j=0;

    printf("Enter the string");
    gets(str);
    len = strlen(str);

    printf("%s",str);


    for(j=0,i=len-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        while(j>=len-1)
        {
            temp[j] = str[i];
            final[j] = temp[j];
            j++;
        }            
    }

    printf("%s",final);       


    putchar('\n');

    getch();

}
```

Any suggestions where am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want a C solution, why tag the question as C++?

Comment: I removed the C++ tag ... Thanks

Comment: What results are you actually getting?  What steps have you taken to try and debug it?

Comment: I am not getting the proper output... I am confused about it...

Comment: You need to split the string "this is a cat" in words first: "this, "is", "a" and "cat".

Comment: By the way, in C++ it would be a one-liner: `std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());` :)

Comment: Any other solution would be appreciated...

Comment: The first step in programming is being precise in what you are trying to implement. According to the example, you do not need to reverse a string as you say, but rather to reverse each word in the string.

Comment: Ya i want to reverse each word in the string... But the format will remain same...

Comment: Correct... But the output which I am getting now is with symbols in the end...

Comment: obviously, this week's homework for Monday is reversing strings. And students are late. Do we had nice weather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h> //for getch()

int main(){
    char str[100];
    char final[100];
    char temp[100];
    int i, j, k;

    printf("Enter the string :");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", str);

    printf("\n%s\n", str);

    for(k=j=i=0;;++i){
        if(isspace(str[i]) || str[i]=='\0'){
            while(k){
                final[j++] = temp[--k];
            }
            if('\0' == (final[j++] = str[i]))
                break;
            //k=0;
        } else {
            temp[k++] = tolower(str[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", final);     

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code...It helped me out

Answer (score 0):

You set `j=0` (actually, you do so twice: once with the declaration, and again in the for-loop initializer).  So, `j>=len-1` is unlikely to be true.  Therefore, the `while` loop does nothing.  As a result, the `for` loop is also useless.  Your whole program consists of a prompt, echo, and no-op.

Comment: So, can you provide me some solution as to how can i achieve the solution...

Right now with my code if I remove the while loop I am getting the reverse string...

Comment: Can you provide me the solution to reverse every word without changing the index of every character.... Like i want to achieve this...

Input:    I want this
Output:   I tnaw siht